# How to replace switch statement in ViewPager Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, switch-statement

I have a class which takes in two string arrays. These arrays contain file names and titles for each file. I am setting up a ViewPager but because these arrays can change depending on the section in the app I cannot use a switch statement. The ViewPager shows fragments which gather data from files in my assets folder.

**Scenario A:**

- fileString[] has length of 4
- fileTitleString[] has length of 4

  ```
  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      Fragment fragment = new myFragment(FILE_PATH, fileString[SELECTION]);

  switch (position) {
  case 0:
      fragment = new myFragment(FILE_PATH, fileString[0]);
      break;
  case 1:
      fragment = new myFragment(FILE_PATH, fileString[1]);
      break;
  case 2:
      fragment = new myFragment(FILE_PATH, fileString[2]);
                  break;
  case 3:
      fragment = new myFragment(FILE_PATH, fileString[3]);
                  break;
  }

  return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
  String title = "";

  switch (position) {
  case 0:
      title = "    " + fileTitleString[0] + "    ";
      break;
  case 1:
      title = "    " + fileTitleString[1] + "    ";
      break;
  case 2:
      title = "    " + fileTitleString[2] + "    ";
      break;
  case 3:
      title = "    " + fileTitleString[3] + "    ";
      break;
  }

  return title;
  ```

  }

**Scenario B:**
 - fileString[] has length of 5
 - fileTitleString[] has length of 5

I know that all that the switch clause does is set up a new fragment but the ViewPager needs to know whats before and after so you can swipe between the fragments.

Comment: Do you just want to replace the `switch` statements with simpler code that does the same thing? Or is there more to your question (involving the "before and after" issue you mention in your last paragraph)?

Comment: Hint: position and the array index. :)

Comment: I just wanted to replace the switch statement so that way the code would determine the amount of files in the file path and make that many fragments. Tried your code Ted but was having a problem and getting an array out of bounds exception just as I was before. For future people see Sipka's answer Worked perfectly and was very easy to follow! Thanks everyone! and Qberticus I was close thanks for the hint =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see you only do this in your getItem method. This replaces the switch

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new myFragment(FILE_PATH, fileString[0]);

    if(position>=0&&position<fileString.length){
        fragment= new myFragment(FILE_PATH, fileString[position]);
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

And in the getPageTitle the same

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String title = "";
    if(position>=0&&position<fileTitleString.length){
        title = "    " + fileTitleString[postition] + "    ";
    }

    return title;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you Sipka, easy to follow. Was close and I see what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the `switch` statements with more compact code, this should work:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new myFragment(FILE_PATH,
         fileString[position >= 0 && position <= 3 ? position : SELECTION]
    );
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return position >= 0 && position <= 3
        ? String.format("    %1$s    ", fileTitleString[position])
        : "";
}
```

You might want to use `fileString.length` and `fileTitleString.length` (respectively) in place of the constant `3` in `getItem` and `getPageTitle` (resp.).